# The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string - .NET MVC 3 #C

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-ce

I'm learning to develop using .NET MVC 3 and C#. I'm attempting to use a 'Code First' approach to create an app but when I try to pull data from my database i'm getting an error message 'The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string'.

I've seen a few other posts about this error but I can't find a solution in those posts that works for me.

I'm using MS Visual Web Developer Express 2010 on Windows 7 64bit. I'm using SQL Compact Server 4.0 as my database.

The error is triggered when this bit of code tries to run:

```
public class StoreController : Controller
{
    MusicStoreEntities storeDB = new MusicStoreEntities();

    //
    // GET: /Store/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var genres = storeDB.Genres.ToList(); // This line causes the error

        return View(genres);
    } 
}
```

My DbContext class is as follows:

```
public class MusicStoreEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
}
```

And my connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>   
  <add name="MusicStoreEntities" 
  connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|MvcMusicStore.sdf"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Is there anything that looks wrong? If you need more info just ask.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you Just need to put "." for localmachine in the data source as follows:

`<add name="MYSQLSERVER"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
     connectionString="Data Source=.\MYSQLSERVER;Trusted_Connection=true"></add>

</connectionStrings>`